# When trying to set title, not sure how to edit it for different pages

Tags: theme-development, themes, title, wp-title

I have this function:

```
function suffusion_set_title() 
{
    global $suf_seo_enabled, $suf_seo_title_style, $suf_seo_title_separator, $suf_seo_show_subtitle, 
    $suf_seo_show_page_num, $paged, $page;

    if ($suf_seo_enabled != 'enabled') {

        if (is_home() || is_front_page()) 
        {
            echo "\t<title>".wp_title('', false)."</title>\n";
        }
        else {
            echo "\t<title>".wp_title('&raquo;', false)."</title>\n";
        }
        return;
    }

    $page_title = wp_title('', false);
    $blog_title = get_bloginfo('name');

    if (is_home() || is_front_page()) {
        $title = $blog_title;
        if ($suf_seo_show_subtitle == 'show') {
            $blog_subtitle = get_bloginfo('description');
            $title .= " ".$suf_seo_title_separator." ".$blog_subtitle;
        }
    }
    else {
        if ($suf_seo_title_style == 'page-blog') {
            $title = $page_title." ".$suf_seo_title_separator." ".$blog_title;
        }
        else if ($suf_seo_title_style == 'blog-page') {
            $title = $blog_title." ".$suf_seo_title_separator." ".$page_title;
        }
        else {
            $title = $page_title;
        }
    }
    if ($suf_seo_show_page_num == 'show' && ($paged >= 2 || $page >= 2)) {
        $title .= ' '.$suf_seo_title_separator.' '.sprintf(__('Page %s', 'suffusion'), max($paged, $page));
    }
    $title = apply_filters('suffusion_set_title', $title);
    echo "\t<title>{$title}</title>\n";
}
```

and I am trying to change how the title appears for some pages, but when I make edits here, they do not show up when I make those edits live.

I use Yoast. Is it possible that Yoast overwrites the values for the  tag?

I use suffusion theme, and this function is in the actions.php file.

The way I have it now, the home page's title is correct. The content pages title is correct.  But the category pages get the homepage title appended to their titles.

And what I am trying to do is append a custom string to those titles and not the string that is currently appended.

Would anyone know how to accomplish that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I use Yoast. Is it possible that Yoast overwrites the values for the tag?

Yes, it is.

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', array( $this, 'title' ), 15, 3 );
```

Snippet above come from "WP SEO by Yoast". In version 1.4.13 it is in line 53 of `class-frontend.php`